# idp initiated SSO

Tags: php, symfony, saml

I'm trying to find a way to log my users from my portal to another service. I'm not very knowledgeable on how SAML SSO works but from what I gather the Portal is the IdP (i.e., us) and I should create a response with certain user-dependent attributes to send to the SP.

I'm using Symfony2 and I read about SimpleSAMLphp but I had troubles installing. The important part is, how should I construct my response? I don't think I should reauthenticate the user since he is already and using the portal.

Thank you and if you found anything illogical please let me know.

Comment: This is a bit too complex to explain briefly. If SP doesn't have authentication information, it redirects your user to IdP (your portal). If IdP doesn't have active user session, it shows login form and user logs in. IdP saves that and creates SAML 2.0 message and redirects your user to SP with that message. If IdP HAD an active user session, it repeats the step without showing login form. From experience, it will be very difficult to set up SSP if you are dealing with this for the first time. There are libraries like LightSaml, but it's not a complete solution like SSP is (IMO, SSP sucks).

Comment: Thank you for you answer and your explination so what do you think i should do because the part that i don't get is how to "send" the saml response with the data needed

Comment: SAML message is an XML document, sent via HTTP GET or POST method to something called Assertion Consumer Service. What you need to do that is establish trust between IdP and SP. This is done via metadata exchange. Then, you have to create SAML message - the XML document with signatures and attributes. Once you do that, you redirect the user to ACS with that message. I simplified the process, these steps aren't trivial and that's why solutions like SimpleSamlPHP are used. Your question is, sadly, too broad for SO and it would take at least 5 full pages to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer N.B but as an idp do i really need to exchange metada or can i directly send the xml response ?

Comment: If you don't perform metadata exchange, SP cannot verify the validity of IdP, thus anyone can send any kind of data to your SP and gain access. That's why metadata exchange is done.

Comment: Thank you can you make your answer as a solution so i can validate it

Comment: I don't think I can qualify my comments as an answer, so I suggest that you try to do your research based on several things I mentioned and let's leave it at that, thanks for the heads up but I'll hold off with posting an answer until I get the time to write a proper, quality one.